# Not able fetch Value from Javascript Array and Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, arrays

First of all I am new to Javascript.I am using an Array which gets its value during runtime like

```
var tablehash = [CS: "CS", tbl_master: "tbl_master"]
```

I have to fetch the value in the Array inorder to compare with a value I had tried like

```
var valtocompare = tablehash ["CS"];
```

but its giving me error  so I had tested the above array manually as

```
var tablehash = {CS: "CS", tbl_master: "tbl_master"}
```

and fetched the value it come correctly

My Question is Why can't I fetch the value from the Array that have `[]` as opening and closing symbols but I can fetch from array that have  `{}` as opening and closing symbols

**Edit:** value `var tablehash = [CS: "CS", tbl_master: "tbl_master"].` is got from the line `tablehash[xx[0]]=xx[0];` in my jquery during runtime it is enclosed with `[]` only what can I do

---

Kindly anyone point me what I am doing wrong.

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in jquery** Question

As I can,t ask a New Question I had added my new Question in this thread because the below mentioned script is in the same Jquery Library.

I am Calling the below mentioned `jQuery` library function from my page but at the line of evaluating my JSON String sent I am Getting the **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

Function called from page as

```
function BindSearchedQueryData(JsonString) {

        $('.sqlbuild').loadSQB(JsonString);
    }
```

The **loadSQB** is

```
loadSQB: function (jsonstr) {
        var $tt = this[0];

        $('.sqlcolumn').remove();
        $('.sqlwhere').remove();
        $('.sqlgroup').remove();
        $('.sqlsort').remove();

        var j=eval('(' + jsonstr + ')');  //Getting Error in this line  

        var coldiv  =$(".addnewsqlcolumn");
        var sortdiv =$('.addnewsqlsort');
        var groupdiv=$('.addnewsqlgroup');
        var wherediv=$('.addnewsqlwhere');

        /*rebuild col data*/
        for(var i=0;i<j.columndata.length;i++){
            //j.columndata[i].columnslot, j.columndata[i].columnvalue
            coldiv[0].opts.onselect(j.columndata[i].columnslot,coldiv,{columnas:j.columndata[i].columnas}); 
        }
        /*rebuild sort data*/
        for(var i=0;i<j.sortdata.length;i++){
            //j.sortdata[i].columnslot, j.sortdata[i].columnas
            sortdiv[0].opts.onselect(j.sortdata[i].columnslot,sortdiv,{columnas:j.sortdata[i].columnas});           
        }
        /*rebuild group by data*/
        for(var i=0;i<j.groupdata.length;i++){
            //j.groupdata[i].columnslot, 
            groupdiv[0].opts.onselect(j.groupdata[i].columnslot,groupdiv,null);                         
        }
        /*rebuild where data*/
        for(var i=0;i<j.wheredata.length;i++){
            //j.wheredata[i].columnslot, j.wheredata[i].opslot,j.wheredata[i].chainslot,j.wheredata[i].columnvalue
            wherediv[0].opts.onselect(j.wheredata[i].columnslot,wherediv,{columnslot:j.wheredata[i].columnslot,opslot:j.wheredata[i].opslot,chainslot:j.wheredata[i].chainslot,columnvalue:j.wheredata[i].columnvalue});            

        }

    }
```

Kindly Anyone point me what is going wrong here

---

Comment: This is not an array. If you want objects, use `{CS: "CS", tbl_master: "tbl_master"}`, if you want arrays, use `["CS", "tbl_master"]`. `[CS: "CS", tbl_master: "tbl_master"]` is just invalid syntax. Please use [JSHint](http://jshint.com) to validate your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript does not have associative arrays, ie you can't have

`var tablehash = [CS: "CS", tbl_master: "tbl_master"]`.

But you can have

`var tablehash = {CS: "CS", tbl_master: "tbl_master"}`, which is a valid object.

Once you do this, you can access the values with `object.key` syntax.

So, the value of `tablehash.CS` would be `CS`.

PS - use a linter in your ide/editor.

Comment: I am getting the specified value `var tablehash = [CS: "CS", tbl_master: "tbl_master"].` from the line  `tablehash[xx[0]]=xx[0];` in my javascript its coming with `[]` only what can I do

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `[]` and `{}` in Javascript.
Values enclosed in `[]` are values in an array and values in `{}` makes `{}` a javascript object.
You can have associative arrays in Javascript like
    `{a: 'apple', b: 'ball'}` .
You can also have arrays as values
    `{a: [1,2], b: [3,4]}`.
So you need to form your hash as
    `var tablehash = {CS: "CS", tbl_master: "tbl_master"}`.
In order to access it you write like
    `tablehash['CS'] or tablehash.CS`

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my Second Question **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

The value which I am passing to the Function **loadSQB** is a `Javascript` Object  so I used the `JSON.stringify()` to convert `Javascript` Object to a `JSON` string

```
loadSQB: function (jsonstr) {
    jsonstr=JSON.stringify(jsonstr); //Solution for the Question
    var $tt = this[0];

    $('.sqlcolumn').remove();
    $('.sqlwhere').remove();
    $('.sqlgroup').remove();
    $('.sqlsort').remove();

    var j=eval('(' + jsonstr + ')');  //Got Error in this line  

    var coldiv  =$(".addnewsqlcolumn");
    var sortdiv =$('.addnewsqlsort');
    var groupdiv=$('.addnewsqlgroup');
    var wherediv=$('.addnewsqlwhere');

    /*rebuild col data*/
    for(var i=0;i<j.columndata.length;i++){
        //j.columndata[i].columnslot, j.columndata[i].columnvalue
        coldiv[0].opts.onselect(j.columndata[i].columnslot,coldiv,{columnas:j.columndata[i].columnas}); 
    }
    /*rebuild sort data*/
    for(var i=0;i<j.sortdata.length;i++){
        //j.sortdata[i].columnslot, j.sortdata[i].columnas
        sortdiv[0].opts.onselect(j.sortdata[i].columnslot,sortdiv,{columnas:j.sortdata[i].columnas});           
    }
    /*rebuild group by data*/
    for(var i=0;i<j.groupdata.length;i++){
        //j.groupdata[i].columnslot, 
        groupdiv[0].opts.onselect(j.groupdata[i].columnslot,groupdiv,null);                         
    }
    /*rebuild where data*/
    for(var i=0;i<j.wheredata.length;i++){
        //j.wheredata[i].columnslot, j.wheredata[i].opslot,j.wheredata[i].chainslot,j.wheredata[i].columnvalue
        wherediv[0].opts.onselect(j.wheredata[i].columnslot,wherediv,{columnslot:j.wheredata[i].columnslot,opslot:j.wheredata[i].opslot,chainslot:j.wheredata[i].chainslot,columnvalue:j.wheredata[i].columnvalue});            

    }

}
```